# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "ContextMenu" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Upon trying to use [native component "ContextMenu"](https://github.com/mpiannucci/react-native-context-menu-view) in my app, I get the error mentioned above:
`Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "ContextMenu" was not found in the UIManager.`
I've tried:

- Restarting computer
- Re-adding and reinstalling things with yarn (not npm)
- A bunch of messing around with pods.
- Re-Cloning the repository
- Many other things i've forgotten because i've been working on this for so long

I use an expo bare project, and test using expo go an an iPhone. Thanks in advance.